# PDO prepared statement to insert data into MySQL

Tags: php, pdo

I am changing all mysqli queries to use PDO now and just want to make sure I'm doing it right.  Here is an old one:

```
$sql = "INSERT into profile (profileid, name, description) values ('$profileid', '$name', '$description')";
        $sql= mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
        if (!$sql) {
        die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
        } else {
        redirect_to('/my-account'); 
        }
```

And here is how I rewrote it:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT into pools (profileid, name, description) values (:profileid, :name, :description)");

$stmt->execute([':profileid' => $profileid, ':name' => $name, ':poolname' => $poolname, ':description' => $description]);

redirect_to('/my-pools');
```

It seemed to work fine when I tested, just want to make sure I did EVERYTHING right.  Does it all look good?

Also, prior to my old mysqli query, I would do this to "sanitize" the data:

```
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['description']);
```

With PDO, I do NOT have to have that AT ALL anymore, is that correct?  Just want to confirm before I delete all the escaping stuff from my code after switching to PDO.

Comment: You can use parametrized queries with mysqli too. You don't have to use PDO just for that. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: this should go on stack overflow since the code is not working... at least i dont think it's working. i think pdo will throw an error because you have too many paramters in your execute call. also, "name" is a mysql keyword so it should be quoted with the backticks.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. It's a keyword, but not a reserved word, so it doesn't need to be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you did everything right, save for the obvious typo with the extra parameter. You can keep with it all right.

The only improvement (which is the point of this site) I can think of is that you can make this code less bloated, with help of positional placeholders.

```
$sql = "INSERT into pools (profileid, name, description) values (?,?,?)";
$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute([$profileid, $name, $description]);
redirect_to('/my-pools');
```

To my taste, this is the most clear and readable approach: now it fits onto screen without horizontal scrolling and you still can visually control the parameter order.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT into pools (`profileid`, `name`, `description`) values (:profileid, :name, :description)");

$stmt->execute([':profileid' => $profileid, ':name' => $name, ':description' => $description]);
```

---

- You're not using the poolname paramter so remove it from the execute call.
- You don't need to do any escaping AT ALL. `mysqli_real_escape_string` requires a mysqli connection to work anyway. You can't mix mysqli stuff with pdo stuff.

Comment: If he needed to do escaping with PDO, he'd translate `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to `$pdo->quote()`.

Comment: Thanks @barmar are there cases when quote might be preferred over a prepared statement?

Comment: mysql keywords don't have to be quoted

Comment: @YourCommonSense `It will work without the quotes because it's not a reserved word`

Comment: Still.. if you have a complicated query it helps readability to quote columns when the table has keywords.

Comment: And why are all the SO people suddenly reading code review?

Comment: You better learn to avoid making mutual exclusive statements as you are confusing yourself and others. Make your mind, whether it "should be" or a "best practice" or would work without. In the end, your statement has no value and only muddling your answer, making it bad for the reader.

Comment: lol was it "bad" for you, common? it wasn't great for me either. i offered a suggestion to improve readability. you're the one wasting my time with semantics.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I can't think of any cases where it's preferable. But the function is there, and my boss uses it (he's old school, and I've only recently gotten him to switch from the mysql extension to PDO).

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, it will work.Also you should consider looking at more options how it can be done.

---

First One would be with **bindParam()**

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT into pools (profileid, name, description) values (:profileid, :name, :description)");

$stmt->bindParam(":profileid",$..);
$stmt->bindParam(":name",$..);
$stmt->bindParam(":description",$...);

$stmt->execute();
```

So what [bindParam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) does is that it bind the variables to the parameter markers.Bound variables pass their value as input and receive the output value, if any, of their associated parameter markers.

---

Second One would be with **bindValue()**

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT into pools (profileid, name, description) values (:profileid, :name, :description)");

$stmt-> bindValue(":profileid",$..,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt-> bindValue(":name",$..,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt-> bindValue(":description",$...,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
```

So what [bindValue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) does is that the variable is bounded as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.

---

Also it can be done the way you done it:

```
execute([':profileid' => $profileid, ':name' => $name, ':poolname' => $poolname, ':description' => $description]);
```

---

> So the question is whats the better approach?

It's up to you :D

- With **bindParam**, you can only pass variables ; not values
- with **bindValue**, you can pass both (values, obviously, and variables)

---

Also how does your connection look like?

> Don't forget to add **charset=utf8** in the connection.

Also you should add **setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false)**, if you are using mysql, because the **PDO** default emulates to emulation ,when using MySql.

If you don't disable emulation you don't get the full protection when using prepares statements.

Comment: This is absolutely pointless answer that does not add any value.

Comment: @YourCommonSense i explained in detail how it can be done.Also i pointed out mistakes that MOST people are doing...I don't see how it doesn't add any value?At least in my case i like when somebody adds extra information so that i can learn more from it.

Comment: The point of this site is to review the existing code, not to retell the PHP manual without any particular aim.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I don't want to be arrogant and i respect you as a person(from the stand point of your programming knowledge).Yes probably the only part would be that i add 'it looks okay than to rewrite the exact same code'.I don't see how it would add any value to it?

Comment: For example Mike Brant answered my questions with a broad explanation where i had the opportunity to learn more and to expand my knowledge.I really don't understand how you can say that it ads no value, can you explain me that part please?

Comment: A knowledge could be relevant and irrelevant. When you ask a question, you aren't looking for just abstract knowledge. You are looking to improve the particular code you posted.  One cannot improve their code based on your answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'l take the most obvious thing that i noted out here 'PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false' you can't say that it's not helpful.

Comment: Well, it is not that helpful. It helps you not to shoot yourself in the foot, but by default the emulation mode is as safe as native mode.

Comment: @YourCommonSense you are a hard person to talk to.Let it be the way you said it...

Comment: I don't want to be a dick, but I hate that hysteria about the emulation mode. Yes, there were errors in mysql and PHP that could have made this mode vulnerable. But they are fixed now. And if you are using a supported PHP version, set encoding in DSN and don't use NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES in mysql, you are perfectly safe.

Comment: @YourCommonSense if we run in a perfect environment where are the latest versions of everything :D